# How to deploy our own TensorFlow Object Detection Model in amazon Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, object-detection-api

I have my own trained TF Object Detection model. If I try to deploy/implement the same model in AWS Sagemaker. It was not working.
I have tried TensorFlowModel() in Sagemaker. But there is an argument called entrypoint- how to create that .py file for prediction?

Answer (score 0):

entrypoint is a argument which contains the file name inference.py,which means,once you create a endpoint and try to predict the image using the invoke endpoint api. the instance will be created based on you mentioned and it will go to the inference.py script and execute the process.
Link : [Documentation for tensor-flow model deployment in amazon sage-maker](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#deploying-directly-from-model-artifacts)
.

The inference script must contain a methods input_handler and output_handler or handler which will cover both the function in inference.py script, this for pre and post processing of your image.

[Example for Deploying the tensor flow model](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/model-deployment-using-aws-sagemaker-8116adea7184)
In the above link, i have mentioned a medium post, this will be helpful for your doubts.